# How To Properly Use Lateral Joins In PSQL

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

When I run the command below, there is a syntax error highlighted at UNION on the last line. I am really not sure why.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT    (final_exp.deploymentyear + number)                            AS deploymentyear1,
              (final_exp.deploymentyear + number) - final_exp.deploymentyear AS diff,
              final_exp.*
    FROM     (
         SELECT number
         FROM   hubb."spt_values"
         WHERE  type = 'P'
         AND    (
                       2000 + number) <= 2023 ) s
    LEFT JOIN lateral (
         SELECT *
         FROM   final_exp
         WHERE  (
                       final_exp.deploymentyear + number) < 2023
         AND    NOT EXISTS
                (
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM   final_exp g
                       WHERE  g.deploymentyear = (final_exp.deploymentyear + number)
                       AND    g.sacstate = final_exp.sacstate
                       AND    g.fund = final_exp.fund
                       AND    g.companyname = final_exp.companyname )
         AND    diff = 1 )df
    UNION
```

I verified parentheses and comments and can't find where the issue might be coming from. Is it the lateral join?

Comment: You must add another select statement after the `union` (or just remove it)

Comment: That's a portion of the code. I do have a select statement in my IDE. I just didn't copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the join condition for the Join portion. You need to join the "S" sub query and the join like "ON df.some_column=s.some_column"